# Использование полученного пути через FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, как использовать выбранный вручную путь к папке, через `FolderBrowserDialog`, чтобы подставить его ко второй кнопке?

При нажатии на вторую кнопку нужно переименовать файл, по выбранному пути первой кнопки.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    DialogResult result = folderBrowser.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // ?
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ? Через путь выбранный в первой кнопке
    File.Move("testOriginal.txt", "testRename.txt");
}
```

Comment: Переименовать выбранную папку или все файлы в ней ?

Comment: Что бы переименовать только файл используйте `OpebFileDialog`

Comment: Файл внутри выбранной папки.

Comment: Тогда нужно открывать этот файл через FileDialog. Почему вы решили использовать FolderDialog ?

Comment: Думал, что выберу папку, получу переменную на нее и смогу подставлять ее к файлам которые необходимо переименовать. На самом деле нужно переименовать два файла разом, не выбирая каждый файл отдельно.

Comment: оба файла в одной папке ?

Comment: Да, допустим файл `testOriginal1.txt` и `testOriginal2.txt` переименовать в `testRename1.txt` и `testRename2.txt`

Comment: ок. подождите секунду

Answer (score 1):

Переименовать все файлы, начинающиеся на "testFile", в "renamedFile" со своими цифрами соответственно

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog browserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (browserDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var folder = new DirectoryInfo(browserDialog.SelectedPath);
        if (folder.Exists)
        {
            var validFiles = folder.GetFiles().Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("testFile"));
            foreach (var file in validFiles)
            {
                File.Move(file.FullName, file.FullName.Replace("testFile", "renamedFile"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за вариант с одной кнопкой, может переосмыслю логику приложения.

Comment: Какие проблемы распилить на две? Вопрос был в получении пути из ФолдерБраузерДиалог

Comment: Я имел ввиду, что вариант с одной кнопкой может даже и лучше :)

Answer (score 1):

```
string FolderPath { get; set; }
string[] OldNames = new string[] { "Test1.txt", "Test2.txt" };
string[] NewNames = new string[] { "testRename1.txt", "testRename2.txt" };

FolderBrowserDialog dialog { get; set; }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    dialog.ShowDialog();
    FolderPath = dialog.SelectedPath;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo direct = new DirectoryInfo(FolderPath);
    foreach (var file in direct.GetFiles())
    {
        for (int i =0; i< OldNames.Length; i++ )
        {
            if (file.Name == OldNames[i])
            {
                File.Move(file.FullName, file.FullName.Replace(OldNames[i],NewNames[i]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, сам бы не смог сформировать такой код.

Comment: @Vitokhv  Пожалуйста, надеюсь помог!)

Comment: можно узнать почему вы откатили правку?

Comment: @FoggyFinder очень незначительная правка. впрочем если вам будет приятно то поправьте еще раз - приму.

Comment: Не возражаете против небольшого обсуждения в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--)? Я бы хотел пояснить свою позицию и услышать вашу точку зрения